# How can i create unity launch icon for Chrome Evernote?

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, evernote

I use Evernote web app and i would like to use it separated from other Chrome tabs, as autonom web app. This is possible when i choose "Open as Window" option in Evernote Web settings. But i would like to have this icon in Unity launcher. With custom name, icon and link(which should open new Chrome Window with Evernote App in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer myself.
Open your desired web page tab in Google Chrome.
Then click Wrench - Tools - Create Application Shortcut. Choose Desktop and Applications. 
Then go to Desktop, you will see web app link there, drag&drop it to Unity.
You can also change its icon by clicking right click-icon.